# Laravel 8 – Eloquent Queries Without Database Migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I’m a newbie with Laravel, but old school PHP developer. I’m in the process of adapting my framework to the Laravel framework.

My main goal at this moment is to use eloquent queries without doing a DB schema and migration inside Laravel, as I have my database is built already, up and running.

So far, I’ve been successful in using eloquent queries to interact with my database. Here’s a part of the code that’s working without any problems:

```
$results = DB::table('my_table')->where('id', '=', 123)->orderBy('title')->get()->toArray();
```

The problem is when I try to limit the fields I want to retrieve from the database. So far, I’ve tried:

```
->select('id', 'title', 'description')
```

and

```
->get('id', 'title', 'description')
```

It returns me an error like so:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' title' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`,  `title`,  `description` from `categories` where `id_parent` = 781 and `activation` = 1 order by `title` asc)
> A column was not found
> You might have forgotten to run your migrations. You can run your migrations using php artisan migrate.
> Pressing the button below will try to run your migrations.**

I know that I could probably accomplish this through raw queries, but my intention is to use some of Laravel´s features that are widely used in tech companies. So, is it even possible to accomplish what I’m trying to using eloquent queries without having to build a DB schema and all migration process? And if so, what would be the way?

One of the main reasons I don’t want to develop a migration and schema is that my database has a prefix for the tables inside my framework that I change according to each project / client and I don’t want to spend some time on how I could build a migration / schema with a prefix and so on.

I´ve checked this stackoverflow link:
[Laravel without Eloquent & database migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428002/laravel-without-eloquent-database-migrations)
But it wasn’t quite what I was looking for.

**Edit - Solution:**
The problem was with a bug that had extra space on the column name. So, the following worked:

```
$results = DB::table('my_table')->select('id', 'title', 'description')->where('id', '=', 123)->orderBy('title')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Eloquent has no dependency to the migrations.

Comment: Unknown column `' title'` 
there is a whitespace before the column name

Comment: can you copy the error message without editing? as pointed @MiladElyasi there is an extra space

Comment: I did´t edit the error message, but @MiladElyasi has a point. Maybe, there is a space in the columns names. I´m gonna check on that and make another test.

Comment: @MiladElyasi - that was it. Working perfectly now. If you want, you can post an answer and I´ll mark it as correct. By the way - it worked with the following code: ```$results = DB::table(‘my_table’)->select(‘id’, ‘title’, ‘description’)->where(‘id’, ‘=’, 123)->orderBy(‘title’)->get()->toArray();```

Comment: Error is in code copy/paste. You have to use correct quote sign around the strings (column names): `'`. Possible cause for issue is copied code from some article and then it is pasted something else which is same character you've pasted here in question. Second, `select()` method accepts array of strings as parameter not multiple parameters. `'my_table' !== ‘my_table’`

Comment: @JorgeMauricio i've posted it

Comment: Are you really using backticks? And why don't you use Eloquent and Models?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden - actually, no. Came out the editor this way. Don´t know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check your column names.
they have to be with no wihtespaces